# panning cesium 2D map having asia as center without zooming

Tags: cesium, pan

Using cesium it is possible to pan the 2D map having Asia as the center?

Example as shown in the image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem by using  cesium 1.34
And the following codes

```
    var target = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(103.85195, 1.290270, 35000000);
    viewer.camera.setView( { destination : target,
    orientation: {
    heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians(90.0), // east, default value is 0.0 (north)
    pitch : Cesium.Math.toRadians(-90),    // default value (looking down)
    roll : 0.0                             // default value
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(0, -89, 170, 89);
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 1.1;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

viewer.scene.morphTo2D(0);
```

Note the `fromDegrees` parameters are: West, South, East, North.

Also note this sets up the default (home) view this way.  If you wanted to pan the camera here at runtime, there are other ways to do this, see the [Camera Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera.html&label=Showcases).

Comment: Hi Emackey,

Please see [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/kHUx9Ew6t0w).

I manager to get it pan but it didn't wrap around however the example [link](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=bdfabff77be1f2e9fd520efff6b892ec) works.

Comment: You might need to upgrade to a more recent version of Cesium.  What version are you using?